# Are Hom-Lie algebras Schreier variety?

Tags: lie-algebras

Lie algebras are Schreier variety, that is, a variety of algebraic systems (i.e., a class of algebras defined by identical relations) in which the subalgebras of free algebras are again free. The variety of abelian groups, commutative and anticommutative algebras are examples of Schreier varieties. Are Hom-Lie algebras Schreier variety?